# DjangoCMS, use snippets outside of CMS templates

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm trying to use django-contact-form in django-cms. django-contact-form has one or two pages (showing a form and a thank-you note), which are represented by django templates

In the left column of these templates I would love to show some general information on contacting us, which should be editable from the CMS.

Now I suppose I could use a `{% placeholder "contact_info" %}` somewhere. But there isn't really the concept of a "contact page", since that's already taken care of by the contact_form app, which simply provides templates (no cms stuff)

My understanding is that I'd need to create some kind of fake contact page & an associated template to even get this to work.

What I'm trying to say is: I want to use an editable snipplet of text (or whatever, but in this case text), from template. How do I do this in Django-CMS?

Incidentally, the link below seems to indicate that this is possible, but not how it's possible.

https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/491

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways I know of to do this in Django-CMS...

One is to create a Django-CMS page and [hook your django-contact-form's urls to it](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/extending_cms/app_integration.html#app-hooks).

The other is to create a shared cms page that isn't included the navigation with a placeholder that you can reference by ID in your django-contact-form app's template(s).

Hope that gets you going.

Comment: Thanks, it does get me going, albeit further in the direction I was going in. I'd prefer to hear about a simpler solution, but if no such solution arises in the coming days I'll accept your answer instead.

Comment: I hear you. I've worked with Django-CMS for quite a while, but I've yet to find a better way. Any takers? I'd love to hear some alternate solutions!

Answer (score 3):

I found a good solution in [this django-cms issue](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/491). Create a template tag, ala `something/templatetags/show_snippet_tag.py`:

```
# From https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/491

from cms.plugins.snippet.models import Snippet
from cms.plugins.snippet.cms_plugins import SnippetPlugin
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def show_snippet(name):
    try:
        return SnippetPlugin().render(
            {},
            type('obj', (object,), {'snippet' : Snippet.objects.get(name = name)}),
            None
        )['content']
    except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
        return "[No snippet named '%s']" % name
```

And then in your template,

```
{% load show_snippet_tag %}
{% show_snippet "My Snippet Name" %}
```

Kaboom.

Comment: This is awesome - and fills a very definite need.  I think this should be added to the snippet plugin core, in fact.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another thought would be that instead of a snippet, you might be able to more easily use a "static_placeholder" - if you are using the new DjangoCMS 3.x.  This then has the added benefit of making it easy for content editors to access and edit the content on every page it is in rather than having to go to the admin interface and hunt down the appropriate snippet name separately.  It will also allow the editor-person to use the more friendly WYSIWYG interface (rather than the manual-code of the snippet) or even add a forms plugin that you have added to your project space.

You can see the quick docs on them here: http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/templatetags.html#static-placeholder